# Android Date format throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android

I'm trying to format an `Calendar` instance time with the use of `SimpleDateFormat` class. It throws an `IllegalArgumentException`. I need to use the same standard throughout all device language preferences.

```
SimpleDateFormat myDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();        
String selectedDate = myDateFormatter.format(c.getTime());



**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: ١٢/٠٤/٢٠١٣
at java.util.Date.parseError(Date.java:367)
at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:420)
at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:156)**
```

Let me have some quick suggestion to fix these issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since SimpleDateFormat is Depreciated

I would suggest you to use this way

```
android.text.format.DateFormat dateFormat= new android.text.format.DateFormat();
dateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm", new java.util.Date());
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'll try and let you know the end result.

Comment: if you cant find solution, just let me know!

Comment: and as @kalyan pvs's suggested. that may be the cause of error. just to get the Time by milliseconds from Calender instance. then hope that'll work